# Setting UUID strategy throw me an error

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, uuid

after a lot of googling and debugging, I can't figure it out why I get an error when using UUID strategy in my Model instance.

I am using localStorage to store remote data on the user's device, ST2 recommands (they says "you need") to use an UUID identifier in my model instance to generate unique ID.

If I don't, I get :

```
[WARN][Anonymous] Your identifier generation strategy for the model does not ensure unique id's. Please use the UUID strategy, or implement your own identifier strategy with the flag isUnique.
```

If I do it, I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined
```

Here is my Model :

```
Ext.define("MyApp.model.News", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config : {
        idProperty: "localId",
        identifier: {
            type: 'uuid'
        },
        fields : [ {
            name: "localId",
            type: "auto"
        },{
            name : "id",
            type : "integer"
        }, {
            name : "title",
            type : "string"
        }[...]],
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id  : 'proxyNews'
        }

    }
});
```

And the localStorage store :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.NewsLocalStorage', {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    config: {
        storeId: 'newsLocalStorage',
        model: "Lmde.model.News",
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I only added the model to an app and it works.
(I guess Lmde = MyApp)

I added to the launch:

```
MyApp.News = Ext.create('MyApp.model.News');
```

Here is the model again

```
Ext.define("MyApp.model.News", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        idProperty: "localId",
        identifier: { type: 'uuid' },
        fields: [
            { name: "localId", type: "auto" },
            { name: "id", type: "integer" },
            { name: "title", type: "string" }
        ],
        proxy: { type: 'localstorage', id: 'myapp.news' }
    }
});
```